# Matlab - Clarification

Tags: matlab

Could someone explain to me what's happening here?

```
yMatrix = eye(num_labels)(y,:)
```

I saw this in an assignment's answers but I couldn't google the answer. I would really appreciate any feedback.

Comment: That's a syntax error.  `(y,:)` only makes sense if you are indexing into a matrix, which you are not here.

Comment: That can run  in Octave but prohibited in MATLAB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, in MATLAB the code that you've posted is a syntax error. In Octave, however, it works.

It's a little easier to see what's happening if we break it into two lines (which is what's required for it to run in MATLAB).

```
% Creates an identity matrix (ones along the diagonal) that is [num_labels x num_labels]
I = eye(num_labels);

% Retrieve the y'th row (and all columns) and store in a matrix yMatrix
yMatrix = I(y,:);
```

In MATLAB, you need this intermediate variable before indexing into it with `y`. In Octave, you can index into the result of a function *immediately* instead.

Comment: Here are some additional info:
num_labels = 10;
y is a vector (5000 x 1)
Is it still performing the same thing?

Comment: @blackknight316 Yes. It creates a 10x10 matrix and grabs the rows that correspond to each element in `y`. So if `y` were `[1 1 2 3]` it would return a 4 x 10 matrix made up of rows `1`, `1`, `2`, and `3` of the identify matrix.